# Monitor long ongoing mysql queries

Tags: mysql, debian, nagios

is there any plugin or possibility to check with nagios MySQL query, which is running longer than for example 1hour? So I get alerted and can manage it?

I use this code, but I am not sure how to transfer it into nagios plugin

```
#!/bin/bash
trigger=20
hostname=server.name
activeQcount=`mysql -e "show full processlist;" | egrep -v "leechprotect|root|Time" | awk -v T=$trigger '{ if ( $6 > T ) print $0}' | wc -l`
if [ $activeQcount -gt 0 ]
then
echo "=====================================================================================" > /tmp/MySQLcheckquery
echo "= MySQL Query Check recognized running script longer than 60mins" >> /tmp/MySQLcheckquery
echo "=====================================================================================" >> /tmp/MySQLcheckquery
date >> /tmp/MySQLcheckquery
echo "" >> /tmp/MySQLcheckquery
mysql -e "show full processlist;" >> /tmp/MySQLcheckquery
echo "=====================================================================================">> /tmp/MySQLcheckquery
cat /tmp/MySQLMon | awk -v T=$trigger '{ if ( $6 > T ) print $0}' | \
mail -s"MySQL Query Check recognized running script longer than $trigger seconds on $hostname"  $trigger seconds on "foo@email.com" -- -r "rob$
fi
```

Comment: Basically you'll have to use NRPE to have nagios remotely issue the execution of your local script and report back to nagios the status of the service. RTFM is your best friend here.

Comment: Check out https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/MySQL